# iOS6 vs iOS7 Appearance Interface Builder

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios6, interface-builder, ios7

I'm a bit confused by how the UI compatibility model is setup in iOS.

It seems you can force iOS6 look & feel while running the app in iOS7 by changing the storyboard/interface builder settings. But when you set it for iOS7 UI, iOS6 devices are unable to install the app.

Is it possible for the app to be rendered with the new flat look in iOS7 and still maintain compatible w/ iOS6 devices rendering the old glossy UI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried one of the following?

- setting the min version of iOS that will run your app
- changing the build for tab under the IB section

For the first one, just go to your project settings, and find 
[image]

then you can just change the 7.0 to whatever version you're running..

For the second one, just open the right panel in IB, and do

[image]

and see if that helps you any.

Hope this helps!